# implement wordpress checksum check

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to implement checksum check for wordpress sites. and send the output via email or pushbullet.
what is the procedure  and steps for this?

i was trying to install wp-cli through this below steps:

```
cd /opt
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar

chmod +x wp-cli.phar
sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
```

but when i execute this

```
wp core version
```

it reports as wp command not found.

by default we have the package wpa_cli in the server.

is wpa_cli also used for the implementing checksum check for wordpress sites?
if so what i need to do?

```
 wpa_cli core verify-checksums
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: Success

 wpa_cli core version
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: Success

 wp core version
-bash: wp: command not found
```